# Access stripping off decimal places when querying SQL server view

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, view

I am running a query that selects data from a SQL Server view. When the data comes back it is rounded to not have any decimal places. This does not happen to every column even though all the columns are defined the same in the SQL base table:

```
[whp]    [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
[whp_si] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
```

In this instance the Access query column `whp_si` shows the decimal places always but `whp` does not, ever.

Looking at the data `whp_si` in SQL, the majority of records have decimal places, whereas the majority do not for `whp`, I cannot believe that this would make any difference but you never know.

When I look at the linked SQL base table via Access in design mode, it interprets both columns as Number, Decimal, Precision 10, Scale 2, Decimal Places Auto. When I look at the SQL view it shows `whp` as Long Integer and `whp_si` as Double.

The view is almost a like for like representation of the the base table, there is no formatting whatsoever. The users can not see the base tables they have to use the views.

Can anybody help me with this, please, as I have searched the entire world wide web, I think.

Base table def:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [id_wellborecompl] [int] NULL,
    [id_validation_level] [int] NULL,
    [id_type_test] [int] NULL,
    [id_status_test] [int] NULL,
    [date] [datetime2](6) NOT NULL,
    [duration] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [q_oil] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [q_gas] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [q_water] [numeric](14, 2) NULL,
    [api] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [bsw] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [gor] [numeric](14, 2) NULL,
    [glr] [numeric](14, 2) NULL,
    [tds] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [choke] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [whp] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [whp_si] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [flp] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [flp_SI] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [wht] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [wht_SI] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [chp] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [chp_SI] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [p_sep] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [p_sep_si] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [t_sep] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [t_sep_si] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [chemical_inj] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [bhp_pip] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [bhp_pip_si] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [q_gl] [numeric](14, 2) NULL,
    [q_jet] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [rpm] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [frequency] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [stroke] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [submergence] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [submergence_si] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [amp] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [pd] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [pd_si] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [volts] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [chole_gl] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [p_jet] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [p_jet_si] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [p_gl] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [p_gl_si] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [pump_eff] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [validity] [bit] NULL,
    [comments] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [last_update] [datetime2](6) NULL,
    [user_update] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [comment] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [deletedAt] [datetime2](6) NULL,
    [create_date] [datetime2](6) NULL,
    [t_motor] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [t_motor_si] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [bh_temp] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [bh_temp_si] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [vibration] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [sand] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Snippet of data returned from table with Select statement:

```
whp whp_si  flp flp_SI
6.6 0.46    NULL    NULL
120.6   8.32    88.9    6.13
128.5   8.87    NULL    NULL
2   0.14    1.8 0.12
2.8 0.19    NULL    NULL
7.1 0.49    NULL    NULL
120.6   8.32    98.8    6.82
128.5   8.87    NULL    NULL
3   0.21    NULL    NULL
9   0.62    NULL    NULL
9   0.62    NULL    NULL
9   0.62    NULL    NULL
7.1 0.49    NULL    NULL
2   0.14    1.8 0.12
2.8 0.19    2.3 0.16
123.3   8.51    82.9    5.72
128.5   8.87    0   0
4   0.28    NULL    NULL
9   0.62    NULL    NULL
7.1 0.49    NULL    NULL
```

View Def:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[V_RAW_Test] AS
SELECT T.[id] AS id
      ,T.[id_wellborecompl] AS id_wellborecompl
      ,T.[id_validation_level] AS id_validation_level
      ,T.[id_type_test] AS id_type_test
      ,T.[id_status_test] AS id_status_test
      ,T.[date] AS date
      ,T.[duration] AS duration
      ,T.[q_oil] AS q_oil
      ,T.[q_gas] AS q_gas
      ,T.[q_water] AS q_water
      ,T.[api] AS api
      ,T.[bsw] AS bsw
      ,T.[gor] AS gor
      ,T.[glr] AS glr
      ,T.[tds] AS tds
      ,T.[choke] AS choke
      ,T.[whp] AS whp
      ,T.[whp_si] AS whp_si
      ,T.[flp] AS flp
      ,T.[flp_SI] AS flp_SI
      ,T.[wht] AS wht
      ,T.[wht_SI] AS wht_SI
      ,T.[chp] AS chp
      ,T.[chp_SI] AS chp_SI
      ,T.[p_sep] AS p_sep
      ,T.[p_sep_si] AS p_sep_si
      ,T.[t_sep] AS t_sep
      ,T.[t_sep_si] AS t_sep_si
      ,T.[chemical_inj] AS chemical_inj
      ,T.[bhp_pip] AS bhp_pip
      ,T.[bhp_pip_si] AS bhp_pip_si
      ,T.[q_gl] AS q_gl
      ,T.[q_jet] AS q_jet
      ,T.[rpm] AS rpm
      ,T.[frequency] AS frequency
      ,T.[stroke] AS stroke
      ,T.[submergence] AS submergence
      ,T.[submergence_si] AS submergence_si
      ,T.[amp] AS amp
      ,T.[pd] AS pd
      ,T.[pd_si] AS pd_si
      ,T.[volts] AS volts
      ,T.[chole_gl] AS chole_gl
      ,T.[p_jet] AS p_jet
      ,T.[p_jet_si] AS p_jet_si
      ,T.[p_gl] AS p_gl
      ,T.[p_gl_si] AS p_gl_si
      ,T.[pump_eff] AS pump_eff
      ,T.[validity] AS validity
      ,T.[comments] AS comments
      ,T.[last_update] AS last_update
      ,T.[user_update] AS user_update
      ,T.[comment] AS comment
      ,T.[deletedAt] AS deletedAt
      ,(SELECT TOP 1 A.id FROM [dbo].[activation] AS A WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE A.id_wellstring = WS.id AND T.date >= A.date_run AND (T.date < A.date_end OR A.date_end IS NULL) AND A.deletedAt IS NULL) AS id_activation
  FROM [dbo].[test] AS T WITH (NOLOCK)
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[wellbore_compl] WC ON WC.id = T.id_wellborecompl
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[wellstring] WS ON WS.id = WC.id_wellstring
```

Snippet of data from View Select statement:

```
whp whp_si  flp flp_SI  wht wht_SI
6.6 0.46    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
120.6   8.32    88.9    6.13    71.4    4.93
128.5   8.87    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2   0.14    1.8 0.12    NULL    NULL
2.8 0.19    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
7.1 0.49    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
120.6   8.32    98.8    6.82    70.9    4.89
128.5   8.87    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
3   0.21    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
9   0.62    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
9   0.62    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
9   0.62    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
7.1 0.49    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2   0.14    1.8 0.12    NULL    NULL
2.8 0.19    2.3 0.16    39  2.69
123.3   8.51    82.9    5.72    65.5    4.52
128.5   8.87    0   0   NULL    NULL
4   0.28    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
9   0.62    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
7.1 0.49    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Access query:

```
SELECT dbo_V_RAW_Test.id, dbo_V_RAW_Test.q_gas, dbo_V_RAW_Test.q_water, dbo_V_RAW_Test.whp, dbo_V_RAW_Test.whp_si, dbo_test.whp, dbo_test.whp_si, dbo_V_RAW_Test.flp, dbo_V_RAW_Test.flp_SI, dbo_V_RAW_Test.wht, dbo_V_RAW_Test.wht_SI, dbo_V_RAW_Test.chp, dbo_V_RAW_Test.chp_SI, dbo_V_RAW_Test.p_sep, dbo_V_RAW_Test.p_sep_si, dbo_V_RAW_Test.t_sep, dbo_V_RAW_Test.t_sep_si, dbo_V_RAW_Test.chemical_inj, dbo_V_RAW_Test.bhp_pip, dbo_V_RAW_Test.bhp_pip_si, dbo_V_RAW_Test.q_gl, dbo_V_RAW_Test.q_jet, dbo_V_RAW_Test.rpm, dbo_V_RAW_Test.frequency, dbo_V_RAW_Test.stroke, dbo_V_RAW_Test.submergence, dbo_V_RAW_Test.submergence_si, dbo_V_RAW_Test.amp, dbo_V_RAW_Test.pd, dbo_V_RAW_Test.pd_si, dbo_V_RAW_Test.volts, dbo_V_RAW_Test.chole_gl, dbo_V_RAW_Test.p_jet, dbo_V_RAW_Test.p_jet_si, dbo_V_RAW_Test.p_gl, dbo_V_RAW_Test.p_gl_si, dbo_V_RAW_Test.pump_eff, dbo_V_RAW_Test.validity, dbo_V_RAW_Test.comments, dbo_V_RAW_Test.last_update, dbo_V_RAW_Test.user_update, dbo_V_RAW_Test.comment, dbo_V_RAW_Test.deletedAt, dbo_V_RAW_Test.id_activation
FROM dbo_V_RAW_Test
WHERE (((dbo_V_RAW_Test.validity)=False) AND ((dbo_V_RAW_Test.deletedAt) Is Null));
```

Snippet from Access query, just a straight Select:

```
id  date    q_oil   q_gas   q_water api bsw gor glr tds choke   whp whp_si  flp flp_SI  wht wht_SI
52001   2017-02-03  60  133 781     92.87   2216    158     192 6   0.46                
52002   2017-02-03  306 20000   27.7    75  8.11    65359   60060       87  120 8.32    88  6.13    71  4.93
52003   2017-02-03  0   0   0                           128 8.87                
52004   2017-02-04  595 274 465     43.87   460 258         2   0.14    1   0.12        
52005   2017-02-04  372 66  2754        88.1    177 21          2   0.19                
52006   2017-02-04  26  127 4       13.33   4884    4233        55  7   0.49                
52007   2017-02-04  272 19724   11.16   75  3.89    72514   69696       85  120 8.32    98  6.82    70  4.89
52008   2017-02-04  0   0   0                           128 8.87                
52009   2017-02-04  71  194 1405        95  2732    131         3   0.21                
52010   2017-02-04  458 290 40      8   634 583         9   0.62                
52011   2017-02-04  39  20  31      44  511 286         9   0.62                
52012   2017-02-04  67  639 24      26  9543    7030            9   0.62                
52013   2017-02-05  29  141 1       3.33    4862    4700        55  7   0.49                
52014   2017-02-05  585 280 470     44.55   478 265     192 2   0.14    1   0.12        
52015   2017-02-05  380 66  2743        87.83   173 21      192 2   0.19    2   0.16    39  2.69
52016   2017-02-05  247 16714   14.26   75  5.36    67668   64038       88  123 8.51    82  5.72    65  4.52
52017   2017-02-05  0   0   0                       0   128 8.87    0   0       
52018   2017-02-05  151 43  394     72  286 79          4   0.28                
52019   2017-02-05  367 247 61      14  673 577         9   0.62                
52020   2017-02-06  32  128 2       5.88    4000    3764        55  7   0.49
```

Comment: Please share the query you are running.

Comment: And the view definition, and the table definition would be good also.

Comment: Sounds similar to [this support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/920359/a-decimal-value-in-a-column-is-rounded-up-or-down-to-an-integer-value)

Comment: `When I look at the SQL view it shows whp as Long Integer and whp_si as Double` Sounds like something is wrong in your view. Why dont you show us the view definition

Comment: Have you tried to script the view out to see if there is any manipulation to the column?

Comment: @user1443098   - done.

Comment: @Sean Lange - done

Comment: @GuidoG - done.

Comment: @ shawkins1  -  done

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever - Yes, this is close but does not give me any actual help but thanks anyway.

Comment: I would advise you not to use NOLOCK, especially in a view. It has a LOT of baggage that most people don't understand. Things like randomly returning missing and/or duplicate rows. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: I would ask why you have a view that hits the test table and then a query in access that hits the view AND the same base table that is in your view. Sounds like the view is inadequate for your needs.

Comment: @ Sean Lange Sorry that is a mistake I was just trying to see what came back when I used the base table directly from Access. The users cannot use the base table. The results were, that the data from the base table returned the decimals while the view still did not.

Comment: Don't put much stock in how SSMS displays the result.  It's just an application, after all.  As is Ms Access.  And in case you are wondering, there's no commitment from Microsoft to align how they display their output.  That's a presentation-layer decision and an implementation detail.  Curious if you run the same query in SQLCMD or Visual Studio or SQL Operations studio if it looks different.

Comment: @ user1443098 Yes very curious and frustrating. Thanks for your interest.